# write value(a, b, c dynamic) in key

Tags: gnuplot

First of all thanks for providing me prompt response. I got query some following query during graph creation.

1. I am trying to create curve fitting graph and have a,b,c value and data points. Is it possible to write a,b,c for each line?. It will be helpful for user. like a=2,b=5.. etc for each quad graph.
2. I tried to create dotted line but could not get success. Is it possible to create dotted line with png terminal?
3. I have to create point on the specific place on the line. is it possible in gnuplot.
4. I have set `png` terminal but I found that `pngcario` is best which is not available for me. Any other terminal which will create better graph?
5. Any other suggestion to improve graph will help me lot (still very far from requirement)
6. I tried to  to create scatter plot by replace **plot with splot** in code But got the following error.
   **Need 1 or 3 columns for cartesian data**

7.The Gnuplot version is : **/remote/gnuplot-4.6.0/bin/gnuplot**

The current `gnuplot` code is:

```
set title 'Approximation Graph'
set term png size 1200 1200
set output 'plot.png'
set xlabel "CLK-D Time (ps)"
set ylabel "CLK-Q Time (ps)"
set style line 1  linecolor rgb "black"  linewidth 1.000 pointtype 0
set style line 2  linecolor rgb "red"  linewidth 1.000
set style line 3  linecolor rgb "black"  linewidth 1.000 pointtype 0
set style line 4  linecolor rgb "blue"  linewidth 1.000
set xrange [-250 : 100]
set yrange [100 : 250]
set xtics 10
set ytics 10
f0_s(x) = a2 * x**2 + b2 * x + c2
fit f0_s(x) 'clk0_s' via 'clk0_s_c'

f1_s(x) = a8 * x**2 + b8 * x + c8
fit f1_s(x) 'clk1_s' via 'clk1_s_c'

f0_h(x) = a14 * x**2 + b14 * x + c14
fit f0_h(x) 'clk0_h' via 'clk0_h_c'

f1_h(x) = a20 * x**2 + b20 * x + c20
fit f1_h(x) 'clk1_h' via 'clk1_h_c'
set style data lines
plot "clk0_h" u 1:2 ls 4 title "clk0_h", f0_h(x)  ls 3  title "clk0_h_quad_g" with steps , \
"clk1_h" u 1:2 ls 2 title "clk1_h", f1_h(x)  ls 1 title "clk1_h_quad_g" with steps, \
"clk0_s" u  1:2 ls 2  title "clk0_s", f0_s(x)  ls 1 title "clk0_s_quad_g" with steps, \
"clk1_s" u 1:2 ls 4 title "clk1_s", f1_s(x) ls 3 title "clk1_s_quad_g" with steps
f0_s(x) = a2 * x**2 + b2 * x + c2
fit f0_s(x) 'clk0_s' via 'clk0_s_c'
```

The GNU Graph:
 [image]

The Requirement Graph:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First some answers to the different points you raised:

1. In order to include the fitted values in the key entry, use `sprintf`:

   ```
   set termoption enhanced
   plot f0_h(x) title sprintf("clk0_h_quad_g: %.1fx^2 + %.1fx + %.1f", a2, b2, c2)
   ```
2. No, `png` doesn't support dashed lines.
3. Yes, you can use e.g.

   ```
   set object circle at graph 0.5, 0.5 radius graph 0.01 fillcolor rgb 'black' fillstyle solid 1.0 noborder
   ```

   to give an example. This must be set before the `plot` command. Instead of using `graph` as coordinate type, you can use also `first` or similar, see `help coordinates`. This requires at least gnuplot 4.4.
4. Why don't you have `pngcairo`? You should use a vector-based terminal like `set terminal postscript eps color colortext enhanced` which should be available in any version. This also supports dashed lines. Afterwards you can convert the output to `pdf` (e.g. with `epstopdf`) or to `png` (using imagemagick's `convert` or any other graphics program) etc.
5. I have no idea why you use the `steps` plotting style. In my other answer I already suggested you to plot the data as points, and the fitted functions as lines (using the same colors for each pair). Using a different terminal than `png` is maybe the most important suggestion! And use less tics.
6. Would you consider `plot "clk0_h" u 1:2 with points` as a scatter plot? Otherwise I still don't know what you want and how it fits in the rest of the questions.

BTW: You should definitely browse through the [gnuplot demos](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_4.6/) to get an impression of the different possibilities and then read through the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for reply.I tried with splot and got errorand update question with more info

Comment: @AbhishekGoswami Again: What do you mean by "scatter plot"? For me a scatter plot is a 3D-representation of non-gridded data, like the first example in http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_4.6/scatter.html. And since its a 3D-plot you need three coordinates. But that makes no sense in the context of your other questions. What do you want to achieve with this? What about my suggestions in point 6?